# About support vector machine classification

Tags: qgis, orfeo-toolbox, image-classification

I want to classify Sentinel 2 images with the SVM in orfeo toolbox in QGIS.
I have made a ROI (2 classes) and use TrainImages classifer (libsvm). I have made a SVM model,but when I use ImageClassification as a results I get a gray images.
Can you help me about this problem. I try evrithing but always I get a gray images.It is a images with a shades of gray. I thinkg that OTB do classification but I dont know why images is gray

Answer (score 1):

The output of the ImageClassification app is an image of labels (integer values), which will appear as shades of gray in most image viewers by default. To get a color image, you need to 'color map', i.e. give a unique RGB color to each class label. You can use the [ColorMapping](https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/CookBook/Applications/app_ColorMapping.html) app from OTB.